# How to change a 'Building Block Gallery Content Control' drop down selection using vba code

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am writing a proposal in which users can select the desired schedule length from a list of building blocks so that they do not have to type in the whole paragraph.

Building Block Options Screenshot

[image]

Is there a way that I can change which option is selected using vba code?

Here is what I have tried so far using a combobox in a userform:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   If ComboBox1.Value = "Based on when drawings can be approved" Then

       Application.Templates( _
       "U:\Documents\2 Estimating Rotation\Repair Template\Repair Proposal 
       Template Rev1.dotm" _
       ).BuildingBlockEntries("Option 2").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
       RichText:=True

   End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   'Schedule Options
   Me.ComboBox1.Clear
   Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Based on when drawings can be approved"

End Sub
```

Is there a way to change the "Selection.Range" to select the desired 'building block gallery content control' drop down? Currently all the code does is insert the text I have stored in 'Option 2' at my cursor location.

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no provision to select an entry from a Building Block content control. All you can do is insert the required building block entry into the content control. This doesn't have to be `Selection.Range`, it can be the content control's `Range`. The content control doesn't care whether what's inserted is from the list, or not - the content control will accept anything.

Assuming this were the first content control in the document, for example:

```
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
Dim tmpl As Word.Template

Set cc = ActiveDocument.Contentcontrols(1)
Set tmpl = Templates("U:\Documents\2 Estimating Rotation\Repair Template\Repair Proposal Template Rev1.dotm")
tmpl.BuildingBlockEntries("Option 2").Insert cc.Range, True
```