# VBA wdContentControlTextGallery populate

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Im trying to populate my wdContentControlBuildingBlockGallery with option 1 in the predefined text template by using

```
ElseIf cc.Type = 5 Then
        ' Set the first selection of the Building Block Gallery
            cc.Range.Text = cc.DropdownListEntries(1).Text
    
End If
```

but `cc.DropdownListEntries(1).Text` is not available for Type 5, is there a similar way to solve it?

I can not find any and ChatGPT cant find any either.

Im trying to poulate Type 5

Complete code

```
For Each cc In wrdDoc.ContentControls
        If cc.Title = "DockID" Then
            cc.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(20, 1).Value
        ElseIf cc.Title = "Adress" Then
            cc.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(10, 1).Value
        ElseIf cc.Title = "Postnr" Then
            cc.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(11, 1).Value
        ElseIf cc.Title = "Namn" Then
            cc.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(4, 1).Value
        ElseIf cc.Title = "Date" Then
            cc.Range.Text = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        ElseIf cc.Title = "dueDate" Then
            cc.Range.Text = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            Dim dueDate As Date
            dueDate = DateAdd("d", 24, Date)
            
            ' Check if the dueDate falls on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
            While Weekday(dueDate, vbMonday) >= 6  ' Saturday = 6, Sunday = 7
                dueDate = DateAdd("d", 1, dueDate)  ' Add one day
            Wend
            
            cc.Range.Text = Format(dueDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        End If
    Next cc
```

Comment: Do you mean `wdContentControlText` from the [WdContentControlType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcontentcontroltype) enumeration? ... though the value 5 in that enumeration equates to `wdContentControlBuildingBlockGallery`. Please clarify and perhaps add more of your code so we can see what you are trying to do in context. Is cc a ContentControl (though I guess 'Object' if you are automating Word from Excel)?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661345/how-to-change-a-building-block-gallery-content-control-drop-down-selection-usi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by doing this,

```
ElseIf cc.Type = 5 Then
        Dim gallery As BuildingBlockEntries
        Set gallery = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries
        Dim template As BuildingBlock
        Set template = gallery.Item("name of the text template")
        template.Insert cc.Range
        Exit For
    End If
```

Huge thanks to all replys.

Answer (score 0):

Just like JohnM said, I do not quite understand what your Template is like either, you did not explain clearly. I'm just trying to think about your line

`cc.Range.Text = cc.DropdownListEntries(1).Text`

, use [BuildingBlock object's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.buildingblock) [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.buildingblock.name) or [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.buildingblock.value) property to do this. Is this right?

```vb
ElseIf cc.Type = 5 Then
        ' Set the first selection of the Building Block Gallery
            cc.Range.Text = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(1).Name
    'or 
            'cc.Range.Text = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(1).Value
End If
```

`ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.` is your template.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having to use **5** to specify the content control type, it's because you haven't used **Tools>References** in the VBE to add the **Microsoft Word Object Library** to your project. That would make your life easier.

Here's the code with correct syntax to add entries to a Dropdown Content Control:

```
Sub AddDropDownCC()
  Dim oCC As ContentControl
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList, Selection.Range)
  With oCC
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Choose an item.", value:=""
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Item 1", "Value 1"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Item 2", "Value 2"
  End With
  Set oCC = Nothing
End Sub
```

It might be necessary to coerce the Excel cell values to strings using:

```
.DropdownListEntries.Add CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(20, 1).Value), CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stella").Cells(20, 1).Value)
```